# IntList Sorting Method

Tags: java

The question that I have is how to implement a sorting method into my IntList class. I am attempting to use the sorting method shown below (Which does not work, merely a starting point), Some things  that I am aware of is this method is INSIDE the IntList class, so I shouldn’t need another file other than IntList and ConsCell.  Things that IntList knows are its constructor and two accessors:  length and print.  IntList is made of ConsCell (linked list) which knows the constructor, getHead, getTail and setTail. If anyone can point me in the correct direction that would be greatly appreciated.

```
// IntList Class
public class IntList {
 private ConsCell start;

 public IntList(ConsCell s) {
  start = s;
 } 
public IntList cons (int h) {
  return new IntList(new ConsCell(h,start));
 } 

 public int length() {
  int len = 0;
  ConsCell cell = start;
    while (cell != null) {
      len++;
      cell = cell.getTail();
 }
 return len;
 }
 public void print() {
   System.out.print("[");
   ConsCell a = start;
   while (a != null){
     System.out.print(a.getHead());
     a = a.getTail();
     if (a != null) System.out.print(",");
   }
   System.out.println("]");
  }

  public static int[] sort(int [] arr){
    int length = IntList.len();
    for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++){
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        int temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

// ConsCell Class
public class ConsCell {
 private int head; 
 private ConsCell tail; 
 
 public ConsCell(int h, ConsCell t) {
 head = h;
 tail = t;
 }
 public int getHead() {
 return head;
 }

 public ConsCell getTail() {
 return tail;
 } 
 
 public void setTail(ConsCell t) {
 tail = t;
 }
}

//Main Class
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    IntList a = new IntList(null);
    IntList b = a.cons(2);
    IntList c = b.cons(1);
    IntList d = c.cons(3);
    
    int x = a.length() + b.length() + c.length() + d.length();

    a.print();
    b.print();
    c.print();
    d.print();
  
    // x.sort() // sorting, will use later

    System.out.println(x);
  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your class IntList does not contain a list. Is it normal ? 
Do you want to sort a list that is contained in the class IntList ?

Comment: I'm sorting a list that is passed in from the Main class. IntList is basically only my methods. The original code is not my own, im modifying it out of a textbook. I hope I was able to explain that fully.